# UITableView with static cells leaking memory

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory-leaks, nsnotifications

I have an app with many screens in a UITabBarController.  The first tab has a UITableViewController with static cells that hold a number of UILabels that display data.  The screen receives notifications and updates the data in the UILabels on a regular basis (once every two seconds).  After running for about 15 minutes the UITableView will scroll very slowly.  If I switch to other tabs they scroll fine.  The memory leak seems to be restricted to the UITableViewController that is receiving the notifications.  My problem is that I can't run leaks or any other tools because I am connected to a device via USB to receive the data.  Can anyone give me any ideas on what I can check for? It's difficult to troubleshoot not being able to connect to XCode.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code you use to handle the notifications and the table view's dataSource? This might not be a memory leak as they are not the only reason for bad performance. Also, they got rare since ARC.

Comment: I found the source of the leak.  It was a method I was using to produce a unique identifier.  It's better now but the cells that contain the labels that are being updated are keeping the tableview from scrolling smoothly.  When the cells go off the screen the tableview scrolls smoothly.  What is strange is that when the app first starts everything is fine.  It seems like it is a accumulative effect.

Comment: My initial comment still is a reasonable request

Comment: I figured out the problem.  I had a button that I used to show a status.  Every time the status changed I added a layer onto it to change the appearance.  I wasn't removing the old layers.  Every time there was an update another layer was added and eventually the large number of layers slowed everything down.